# Making Container fluid on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a container with a panel and a panel body. When I view the site on the desktop, it looks relatively okay. But when I look at it on my phone, there seems to be a huge space on the right with nothing there.

Image depicting the issue http://snag.gy/ApnWS.jpg

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKqpRe

I'm wondering how do I fix the issue? I tried setting container-fluid but I don't like how the display is on the desktop. I'm not even entirely sure if container-fluid would fix my issue. If I can get tips or suggestions please. I'm also very open to changing my article layout. My first time writing an article page, any tips or suggestions would be grand.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-9">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h3>
                            NFL Tutorial <small>Posted on January 25th</small>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://google.com" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                <h4>
                                    <b>1. Football is an 11 vs 11 sp
```

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: I believe the reason why it's not reproducible is because OP's issue is device specific. @Master what devices are you using to test the mobile dimensions?

Comment: What is the CSS on those social icons at the bottom? They are not in the provided code and looks like it could be pushing things over...

Comment: Hi I'm using a one plus one. I tried removing the social icons as you said, still coming across the extra area.

Comment: You have a good amount of invalid HTML that should be fixed before anything else.

Comment: I don't think it's the panel or the container. Would be great if you could include all of your html and css. To help pinpoint the issue, try removing all of the html within the container and seeing what effect that has to mobile. If that fixes the issue, slowly add back more and more.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
```

try writting

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9">
```

Just an idea, I also cannot reproduce it...

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { .container { width: 100%; padding: 0px } }
```